# How to remember only first value passed into object's method?

Tags: java, java-8

I have created a simple class:

```
class Compute{
    public Compute count(Function func){...}
}
```

So I can call this method in a chain like this: `compute.count(function).count(function).count(...)`, but I would like to remember only first function I have passed. I have done it by adding a global boolean into class:

```
 class Compute{
        private boolean first;
        private Function func;
        public Compute count(Function func){ if(first){this.func = func; first = false}...}
    }
```

but also I think it is not a good solution. Is there any better way to solve it?

Comment: What does `count` do? Are you returning the same `Compute` object each time the method is chained or a new one each call?

Comment: Initially your field `func` will be null, so you can do `if(func != null){ this.func = func}`.  Other than that, there's no 'cleaner' way to store it since you don't keep which iteration you're on.

Comment: `Function`? If you mean the class from the package `java.util.function`, then you should add type arguments.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing a function every time if you ignore it most of the time?

Comment: Without the *actual code* this is really unclear in terms of what you are doing at present and what are you looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using boolean you could check if func is null and assign it only if it is. Of course it only works if you don't initialize it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can overload `count()`:

```
class Compute{
    private boolean first;
    private Function func;
    public Compute count(Function func) { ...}
    public Compute count() { ... }
}
```

Now you can do

```
compount.count(function).count().count().count();
```

Or you can pass the `Function` object into a constructor:

```
class Compute{
    private boolean first;
    private Function func;
    public Compute(Function func) { this.func = func}
    public Compute count() { ... }
}
```

and do

```
Compute comput = new Compute(function)
compute.count().count().count();
```

This last option makes it clear that storing the function only happens when the `Compute` object is created.

Answer (score 0):

A builder patter may help. If you define a class like

```
class Compute {
      private final Function function;
      public Compute(Function function) {
           this.function = function;
      }
      public Compute count(){
         // your code
      }
}
```

then you can create a builder like

```
public class ComputeBuilder {
    private final Computation computation;

    public ComputeBuilder addFunction(Function function) {
        computations.add(new Computation(function))
    }

    public ComputeBuilder addComputation(Computation computation) {
        computations.add(computation)
    }

    public Computation build(int iteration) {
        Computation result;
        for (int index = 0 ; index < iteration; index++ ) {
            if (index > 0) {
                result = result.count();
            }
            result = computation.count();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and in the end is a builder that you may reuse multiple time without rewriting it. 
I hope it helps.